# skip to item of index number... on iOS Media Player with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, media-player

I would like to skip to another song using the index number of an item (that you can find with playlist.indexOfNowPlayingItem). Is there an easy way to do that with a function like mediaplayer.skipToNextItem but setting the index number ( for example mediaplayer.skipToItem(4) if i want to skip to the fourth item of my playlist) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, creating a collection as `MPMediaItemCollection`, to set the song to play with : `player.nowPlayingItem = collection.items[1]`

for example :

```
var query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
var collection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: query.items!) //it needs the "!"
let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()

player.setQueueWithItemCollection(collection)

player.nowPlayingItem = collection.items[1]
```

Note : Ifound the answer here : [Play Song at specific index of MPMediaItemCollection in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292774/play-song-at-specific-index-of-mpmediaitemcollection-in-swift/31292875#31292875)

Answer (score 0):

If you check Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221-CH1-SW32), you can see that there are only methods for skipping to next, beginning and previous item. However there is a property `nowPlayingItem` which enables us to either get current track, or set track to play, question is how did you set you current queue of songs...

Let's assume you're using:

**1. Media item collection**:

```
var songs = [song1, song2]
var player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
var collection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: songs)

player.setQueueWithItemCollection(collection)
```

So to set new song to play we just do this:

```
player.nowPlayingItem = song2 (it must be already in our collection)
```

Or if you want to use index number, since we have our songs in array, we can do also:

```
player.nowPlayingItem = songs[1]
```

**2. Media Query**

```
var query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery() // query of songs sorted by name
var songs = query.items as NSarray
var player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()

player.setQueueWithQuery(query)
```

Now to set new song to play we just do this:

```
player.nowPlayingItem = songs[1]
```

Comment: First, thanks for your quality answer ! But doing as you said using the Media Query it tell me "use of undeclared type NSArray" after declaring songs. I tried the first way creating a Media Item collection with my query but after player.nowPlayingItem = songs[1] it tell me "Cannot subscript a value of type MPMediaItem? with an index of type (). So i searched for other questions about nowPlayingItem and i found the answer, witch is to create a collection, set queue with that collection, and then set the song to play like that :  player.nowPlayingItem = collection.items[1]